How am I supposed to report an obviously incorrect answer if I can't downvote, comment, or flag?
I saw an answer to a question which completely misinterpreted it and does something completely different; it is also very short and lacks explanation.
What am I supposed to do with one reputation only, meaning I can't downvote, comment, or even flag the answer?

Somewhat related: Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?. Read the second paragraph in the answer.

Re "which completely misinterpreted it ... also very short and lacks explanation": That is consistent with blind plagiarism (though not much is known about it). There are many undetected completely bogus answers on Stack Overflow.

What site? You currently have 123 reputation points on Stack Overflow. For all sites except Stack Overflow, it says (my emphasis) "Last seen more than a week ago" or "Last seen more than a month ago". So it is likely Stack Overflow.

@This_is_NOT_a_forum Unix Stack Exchange

Once you have 20 network-wide rep, which you currently do, you could try going to one of the chat rooms and mentioning the answer there.

Since you are convinced that that answer is wrong, that implies that you know what the right answer is. Or at least you understand the question and have some ideas regarding a correct answer. So do some research and write an answer.

@PM2Ring There are good answers already.

One approach would be to create a Saves list called, for example, "Flag as Not An Answer" (with an explanation why as a private note, if necessary) and add that answer to that Saves list.
If you really want to know what happens to that answer, then you can also follow it by clicking the "follow" button below the answer.
Eventually, you will either accumulate the reputation on that site to comment, etc., or you will accumulate a reputation of 200 on another site, and then you will get the association bonus of 100 for that site.
You may well find that, by the time you have accumulated the reputation to comment, etc., the post has been edited or deleted, or you may have changed your mind about the "obviously incorrect" answer.

You could comment pointing out it doesn't answer the question or alternatively post a correct answer if you haven't done so already. In theory you could then use the accrued reputation to downvote
If its patentently and completely obviously a non answer, you could also try a Not An Answer flag, but how well it works can vary.

I don't have comments either. Nor flags.

@W.O Are you sure? https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Oh, my. Sorry I was quite wrong. I didn't realize. @roundabout

A flippant answer would be "engage more on the site or get 200 reputation somewhere. A more serious answer is I'm unsure what's the right way for a "low rep" user who has almost no reputation on a site to do more advanced meta moderation tasks. Quality control very much is a meta-moderation task that expects a certain level of platform and subject matter expertise.

The answer is not relevant to the actual question, sadly. (OP with 1 rep only, can't even flag.)

OP never said that tho- and I'd argue this is a perfect opportunity to do what I said into action :D. What should an OP with 1 rep only do?

Well OP didn't explicitly said something wrong either, it's case of not enough details leading to confusion and misleading question. But your previous comment is actually a fitting answer to the question.
